# how to remove header from registration page?

Tags: buddypress, user-registration

How can i remove the header,search and my home,activity,forum etc from registration page.os there any plugin to modify registration page.I am using buddypress plugin.I do not want to call color.css for my registration page.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/frisco-for-buddypress

Comment: Is not including color.css *all* you want to do?

Comment: yes @bungeshea i do not want to include color.css in registration page.Is there any simple way?

Comment: See [my answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77267/19726) below to remove color.css from registration page.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind editing your themes files, you can remove color.css from the registration page by editing the `functions.php` file and change [line 127](http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/frisco-for-buddypress/1.6.13/functions.php#L127) from:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'frisco-color-css');
```

to:

```
if ( ! is_page( 'register' ) ) wp_enqueue_style( 'frisco-color-css');
```

Otherwise you can include a function in a plugin or similar:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if ( is_page( 'register' ) )
        wp_dequeue_style( 'frisco-color-css' );
});
```

You will need to change `register` to the name, slug or ID of your registration page.

Answer (score 0):

The theme you are using is a child theme of Buddypress default theme. You can override any file in the default theme by copying that file from the default theme directory (`wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/`) to your child theme directory (`wp-content/themes/child-theme/`) and placing it in the same sub-folder relative to `bp-default`.

In your case, first you need to copy `register.php` file located in `buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/registration/` sub-folder to your child theme (`themes/frisco-for-buddypress/registration/register.php`).

Next to remove the header elements of this template, create a new custom header file in your theme root directory and call it for example `header-register.php`. Copy the content of the `header.php` to the new file and remove the elements that you want to remove (the search `<form>` and the `wp_nav_menu` elements), and save the file.

Now open the `register.php` file that you just copied, and change the `get_header('buddypress')` at the top of the file to `get_header('register')`. This way you theme will use your custom header for the registration page.

Comment: There is no folder of registration in frisco for buddypress

Comment: @user1916876: You need to create one.

Comment: oh man! I just did it.thanxx a ton.it was very helpful.thanxx again :)

Comment: I am facing same problem for my homepage also.I have installed wordpress in www.mysite.com/user now the problem is that anybody can access the same thing which was my previous problem.my login page is at www.mysite.com/user/wp-login.php but if anyone enters in www.mysite.com/user he will be able to see all the stuff.how can i edit this?i just want to hide everything from www.mysite.com/user ? this is my /user page http://awesomescreenshot.com/004r2uj47